# running complications with parameters

Tags: java

If you put in a fractions like 3/7 the program will then ask you if you want to scale 1:up or 0:down. Then it asks you to enter a scale factor. So if you put in 3/7 and then you want to scale by 1:up then you enter the scale factor of 2, then the output will be 6/7.  My program compiles but it doesn't output anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FractionScale {


    private static final int factor = 0;

    private int numerator;

    private int denominator;

    private int scale;

    private int ScaleFactor;

    //Scanner Input

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter numerator: ");

        int numerator = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter denominator:");

        int denominator = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numerator + "/" + denominator);

        System.out.println("Scale up or down (1:up, 0:down):");

        int scale = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a Scale Factor:");
        int ScaleFactor = userInput.nextInt();



    }



    // Constructors

    public FractionScale(int num, int denom) {

        numerator = num;

        denominator = denom;

    }

    public FractionScale() {

        numerator = 0;

        denominator = 1;

    }

    public FractionScale(int num) {

        numerator = num;

        denominator = 1;

    }

    // creating Fraction object

    FractionScale f = new FractionScale(numerator, denominator);

    // method

    public int getNumerator() {

        return numerator;

    }



    public int getDenominator() {

        return denominator;

    }



    int num = f.getNumerator();

    int denom = f.getDenominator();



    public void setNumerator(int num) {

        numerator = num;

    }



    public void setDenominator(int denom) {

        denominator = denom;

    }





    public FractionScale scaledown(int factor) {

        if (ScaleFactor == 0) {

            System.out.println("Error: Scalefactor cannot be 0");

        }



        int denom = denominator * ScaleFactor;

        FractionScale result = new FractionScale(numerator, denom);

        return result;

    }



    public FractionScale scaleup(int factor) {

        int ScaleFactor = factor;

        int num = numerator * factor;

        FractionScale result = new FractionScale(num, denominator);

        return result;

    }



    public int scale(int factor, boolean flag) {

        if (ScaleFactor == 0) {

            System.out.println("Error: Scalefactor cannot be 0");
        }
        if (scale == 1) {

            flag = true;

        } else {
            flag = false;


        }
        int ScaleFactor = factor;
        return factor;



    }

    public FractionScale add(FractionScale f) {
        int num = numerator * f.denominator + f.numerator * denominator;
        int denom = denominator * f.denominator;
        System.out.println("scaled fraction is" + num + "/" + denom);
        return f;
    }

}
```

Comment: You say there is no output. Have you verified that your input is assigning correctly to the variables you declare? You might not be consuming the newline character when you use Scanner.nextInt(). Try Integer.parseInt(Scanner.nextInt());

Comment: Your program has no code after you enter a scale factor.  It accepts the input and then ends. If you want your program to print things, add some code which prints things.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method your program terminates after accepting input for a scale factor.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter numerator: ");

        int numerator = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter denominator:");

        int denominator = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numerator + "/" + denominator);

        System.out.println("Scale up or down (1:up, 0:down):");

        int scale = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a Scale Factor:");
        int ScaleFactor = userInput.nextInt();


        //there's nothing here to actually print stuff
    }
```

See @azurefrog 's comment.